# Return multiple Promises (Firebase Cloud Functions)

Tags: javascript, promise, google-cloud-functions

I have a Firebase Cloud function that adds a newly authenticated user into the Firestore Database.

### Current Function

```
exports.createUserAccount = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
    const uid = user.uid;
    const privateUserInfoRef = admin.firestore().doc(`/privateUserInfo/${uid}`);
    return privateUserInfoRef.set({
        isAnonymous: true,
        avgRating: 0,
        numRatings: 0,
        loggedInAt: Date.now()
    });
});
```

However, I'd like to return another promise after return `privateUserInfoRef.set({` has completed.

I'd like to shift the `avgRating` & `numRatings` and set it on `admin.firestore().doc('/publicUserInfo/${uid}');` instead.

Comment: so, `privateUserInfoRef.set` returns a Promise? use `.then` to chain the next promise

Comment: Can you provide more info on the .then chain?

Comment: `somePromise.then(function(result) { return someOtherPromise; }).then(function(resultofOther) { ... })` and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
return privateUserInfoRef.set({
    isAnonymous: true,
    avgRating: 0,
    numRatings: 0,
    loggedInAt: Date.now()
})
.then(() => {
    return admin.firestore().doc(...).update(...);
});
```

`then` returns a promise that will propagate up to the `return` statement.  Keep chaining `then` blocks to do more async work.  Cloud Functions will wait until the entire chain is done.  This is basic promise handling in JavaScript (but it gets easier with async/await syntax).

I strongly suggest learning extensively about JavaScript promises work in order to make effective use of Cloud Functions on nodejs.  It will save you a lot of time in the future.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to run multiple operations, once after the other, and return the result of the final one (or the first one that fails), you can chain the `then()` clauses:

```
return privateUserInfoRef.set({
  isAnonymous: true,
  avgRating: 0,
  numRatings: 0,
  loggedInAt: Date.now()
}).then((resultOfSet) => {
  return anotherRef.set(...); 
});
```

You can repeat this chain for as long as needed.

---

If you have multiple operations that can run in parallel, you can alternatively use `Promise.all()` to return the combined result of all of them:

```
return Promise.all([
    privateUserInfoRef.set(...)
    anotherRef.set(...)
]);
```

The return value will be an array with the results of the individual `set()` operations.

---

I'm just using `set()` operations as an example here. This pattern applies to any call that returns a promise, including (for the Realtime Database) `once()` and `push()`, but also for non-Firebase operations that return promises.